Async calls on .Net-8.0 MAUI Blazor app do not work on iOS platform, works on Android and Windows - OpenAppPackageFileAsync() issue on iOS
Creating an app in .NET (8) MAUI BLAZOR HYBRID
The works initializes on Android, Windows and iOS. However, the data is retrieved and shown on Windows and Android only. the iOS platform doesn't fetch the data. It displays the page without data and doesn't reload it (obviously the data isn't fetched anyway). I placed a breakpoint, it doesn't execute or come to the following line of code:
SharedData.SharedDataBundle = Global.DataBundleCollelction;

The Problem
The observation is that, the async call below is not respected on iOS platform. Windows and Android do wait until the async call is finished and continue with the data though.
Not sure how to fix it, I have tried many way of calling it but async-await Task.Run() or Task.WhenAll() do not seem to be working on iOS.
Startup code
The code in the App.Xaml.cs is like below:
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        [Inject] SharedDataService sharedDataService { get; set; }

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sharedDataService = new SharedDataService();
            
            var tasks = new List<Task>
            {
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    Global.DataBundleCollelction = await sharedDataService.UpdateSharedWeatherData(new List<int> { 1, 2, 4, 25, 26, 91 });
                    SharedData.SharedDataBundle = Global.DataBundleCollelction;
                }),
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    var bundle = Global.DataBundleCollelction;
                    var weatherSettingsService = new WeatherSettingsService(bundle);
                    var weatherSettings = await weatherSettingsService.LoadSettingsAsync();
                })
            };

            Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }

Please guide me what am I missing?
UPDATE:
I am using the following method to read JSON files from /Resources/Raw/MyJson.json (MauiAsset)
public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> ReadJsonDataAsync<T>(string jsonDataFileName)
{
    ObservableCollection<T>? genericTypeList = new();
    var isExist = await FileSystem.AppPackageFileExistsAsync(jsonDataFileName);
    if (isExist)
    {
        var stream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(jsonDataFileName);
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var contents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        genericTypeList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObservableCollection<T>>(contents);
    }
    return genericTypeList!;
}

Observation/Answer
The above function reads the JSON file as MauiAsset. That file path was given as 'Resources/Raw/MyJsonFile.json' - this path worked fine for Android and Windows but iOS didn't like it.
It now works, the link shared by (@Alexandar May - MSFT) in the comments below, led me to the solution.


Are you testing on a simulator or a real device? 2. What is SharedDataService, SharedData , Global and what WeatherSettingsService you are using, see how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and add it to your post.


@AlexandarMay-MSFT
(1). Simulator
(2).  I renamed some of the variables and removed a few lines of code to maintain the privacy.
(3). SharedDataService provides shared data between different projects (stored in JSON  format).This is where main data comes from. This data gets processed further before it is shown.
(4).  WeatherSettingsService is a service which is used for app settings. For now it can be ignored.

I replaced the two tasks with the simple log function, run in ios simulator. It can execute the function and get to the breakpoint. So I think it is related with the service you wrote in the Tasks. Also sharedDataService(should be Public).

@AlexandarMay-MSFT I also tried just async calls even var file = await FileSystem.AppPackageFileExistsAsync("Resources/Raw/parts.json"); with/without await... doesn't work on iOS. Everything else was and is still working on Windows and Android. Tried on different  iOS simulators. read about await...async doesn't work for iOS and they are using .Result which is absurd! Only for iOS I will destroy the performance on other platforms?! I am sure there must be another way to handle async calls for iOS platforms.

The FileSystem.AppPackageFileExistsAsync("Resources/Raw/parts.json") which is not working may be related with https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12635, you can follow up there.

@AlexandarMay-MSFT The link shared by you above led me to the solution. The JSON files were not read by iOS and the reason was the same as in the link shared above by you. Kindly, make that as an answer to the question and I will mark it as answered.

This is a known issue tracked on Github: AppPackageFileExistsAsync Doesn't Work On Linked File with MAUI Assets #12635.
To fix it, you can write a link to assets in your csproj file like:
 <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />

Then you can read the file like:
var isExist = await FileSystem.Current.AppPackageFileExistsAsync("MyJsonFile.json");


An fact, this line is the key. <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />, after the in the code, just refer to the file as.... var isExist = await FileSystem.Current.AppPackageFileExistsAsync("MyJsonFile.json"); - notice there is no mention of 'Raw/'. It needs to be done this way if you want  it to work on iOS platform. @Alexandar May - MSFT, please update the answer. it is somewhat not correct and misguiding.

@wafers Done, thanks for the correction. :)
